# jquery slider returning inconsistent values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

Below is the initialization event from my backbone view. Nothing crazy in here, just a quick check to see if the browser supports the HTML5 `range` input type, and if not append the jquery slider.

Everything works fine in a normal browser (i.e. Chrome, Firefox, IE10+) when I'm simply using the HTML `range` slider. However if I use the jquery slider I get consistently inconsistent values.

For example is I slide the slider back and forth, the starting/ending values never equal 0 or 100, as specified in the code. Instead you'll see something like the screen shot below, where the returned value is equal to 5, despite the fact that the handle has been moved as far left as possible.

[image]

Conversly, the value on the far right is rarely 100, again as specified in the code. The screen shot below shows the slider as far right as it can go with a value of 82

[image]

```
var SliderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#inputElements"),

    initialize: function() {
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.range) {
            //IE9 or less
            $('td#sliderContainer input#slider').remove();
            $('td#sliderContainer span').after("<div id='slider'></div>");
            $('#slider').slider({
                range: true,
                step: 1,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
            });
        } else {
            //People friendly browsers so... for now carry on
        }
    },

    events: {
        "slide": "updateJquerySliderVal", //Captures jquery slide event for IE9 or less
        "input #slider": "updateSliderVal" //Captures HTML5 range slider input            
    },

    updateJquerySliderVal: function() {
        var val = this.$el.find('#slider').slider('option', 'value');
        console.log(val);
        this.model.set({ slidervalue: val });
    },

    updateSliderVal: function() {
        var val = this.$el.find('#slider').val();
        this.model.set({ slidervalue: val });
    }
});
```

Comment: So I went through the trouble of trying to replicate your scenario. However, you haven't provided enough information to do so accurately.
The biggest problem is that the slider settings you are using do not create the same type of sliders in the images you provided.

Comment: So I've tried using cdnjs.com and jsdelivr.com for the backbone/underscore scripts in my fiddle and I keep getting either "Backbone undefined" or "Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined" errors. Any trick to adding these scripts on jsfiddle?

Comment: To my understanding, jsfiddle does not support ie9. Neither does [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), except in output mode.
For example: [JS Bin edit mode](http://jsbin.com/qarakitota/4/edit) does not work in ie9. [JS Bin Output Only Mode](http://jsbin.com/qarakitota/1/) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to [rangeslider.js](http://andreruffert.github.io/rangeslider.js/), instead of the standard jQuery slider, solved the problem.